# How can i verify more params with _hashTypedDataV4 from openzeppelin?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, signature, openzeppelin-contracts, eip712

i'm trying to implement a 712 typed signature with openzeppelin:
The contract has two functions:

```
struct ProofData {
    address user;
}

bytes32 constant TYPE_HASH_EASY = keccak256("ProofData(address user)");    

function hash(ProofData calldata data) internal view returns (bytes32) {
    return
        _hashTypedDataV4(keccak256(abi.encode(TYPE_HASH_EASY, data.user)));
}

function verify(
    address signer,
    ProofData calldata data,
    bytes memory _signature
) public view returns (bool) {
     return
         SignatureChecker.isValidSignatureNow(
             signer,
             hash(data),
             _signature
         );

}
```

This implementations works, but if i try to add other params like this:

```
struct ProofData {
    address user;
    address otherUsers;
}

bytes32 constant TYPE_HASH_EASY = keccak256("ProofData(address user, address otherUsers)");
```

And change the hash function like this:

```
function hash(ProofData calldata data) internal view returns (bytes32) {
    return
        _hashTypedDataV4(keccak256(abi.encode(TYPE_HASH_EASY, data.user, data.otherUsers)));
}
```

I set a test like this:

```
        it("Should work easy", async () => {

const domain = {
    name: "name",
    version: "1.0.0",
    chainId,
    verifyingContract: contract.address,
}
const type = {
    ProofData: [
        { name: "user", type: "address" },
        { name: "otherUsers", type: "address" },
    ],
}

const data = {
    user: accounts[1].address,
    otherUsers: accounts[2].address
}

        const signature = await accounts[2]._signTypedData(
            domain,
            type,
            data
        )

        const result = await contract.verify(
            accounts[2].address,
            data,
            signature
        )

        expect(result).to.equal(true)
    })
```

Here i'm signing a mx, and than run the check, the signature is the same, so it should return true, instead it return false.
When i try with only 1 parameter, it return true, so it is correct.

The implementation doesn't work.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include the error that makes you think it doesn't work? like what makes you say it doesn't work, what did you tried to do?

Comment: I just added to the description!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved deleting spaces from struct.